# Can't compile a simple C++ program using g++

Tags: 14.04, compiling, c++, g++

When I try to compile any `c++` program using `g++` I get the following error, the stack trace is really long, this is just a sample:

```
........... 
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:2: error: stray ‘\330’ in program
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:2: error: stray ‘\330’ in program
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:2: error: stray ‘\340’ in program
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:2: error: stray ‘\5’ in program
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:2: error: stray ‘\260’ in program
In file included from /usr/include/endian.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/ctype.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cctype:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/localefwd.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from post_test_5.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:1:1: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:11:2: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/endian.h:60:0,
                 from /usr/include/ctype.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cctype:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/localefwd.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from post_test_5.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:26:31: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
```

And example code is`post_test_5.cpp`:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {

  std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And I try to run it as:

```
g++ -c post_test_5.cpp
```

My `gcc` version and ubuntu versions are:

```
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
kirill@kirill-ThinkPad-X140e:~/CPlusPlusStuff/PostTest$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

However, when I use `gcc` command to compile `.c` file everything works correctly.

What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like (at least) file `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h` have been somehow corrupted. Open it with a text editor and check whether it looks like a normal C++ header file.

If this is the case reinstall package libc6-dev with the command `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libc6-dev`

If this is not the case you will need to post here the full content of file post_test_5.cpp as well as the full output of the compilation.

Comment: It was the `byteswap.h` file, your suggestion fixed the problem. Thank you very much. Do you have any idea of what could've possibly corrupted that file?

Comment: @Akavall Strange... Can you post the broken version of the file somewhere? (Just curious)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel, I no longer have it, sorry. Probably should've saved it..